# Twitter friendships/create API with age screened accounts

Tags: twitter

Im using the following endpoint - https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/friendships/create - to follow Twitter accounts. However it does not work when attempting to follow age restricted accounts, for example https://twitter.com/StellaArtoisUK as you have to specify your age when attempting to follow them in the web browser.

Am I able to pass the parameter of my age with the call to the endpoint or is this functionality not currently supported by API 1.1?

Answer (score 0):

The API documentation makes no mention of such a parameter.  However, according to the [Age Screening page on Twitter.com](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20169945-age-screening-on-twitter), so long as the user has entered their age through the web browser at some point, they'll never be prompted again.  So, if you can catch this exception in your code, you could show your user a message explaining that they need to visit this page from a web browser before viewing it in your application.